# Debugging in VS2012 with NUnit without throwing exceptions?

Tags: c#, debugging, nunit

I have NUnit running into VS2012 with the NUnit Test Adapter and I can do Run All tests fine, but if I want to Debug All Tests every time I hit an Assert it throws an exception. How do I make it not throw exceptions for Asserts? Am I doing something horribly wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the debugger is attached, failed asserts throw exceptions. This is intended behaviour. No need to be alarmed.

You *can* stop Visual Studio from stopping at certain exceptions, by going into Debug -> Exceptions... and unchecking all or some items in the appropriate group, from the column "Thrown" in the "Break when an exception is:" box.

[image: The Exceptions dialog box]